# Can you receive an XmlDocument through asp net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmldocument

I am writing a web service that receives an xml string and parses it to an XmlDocument before doing some other logic on that string. This web service has time intensive constraints, so I want to do this operation as efficently as possible. Is there any way to receive an XmlDocument in Asp .NET using .NET Core 3.1? If not, is there any more efficient way than loading the following?

```
// xml is the xml string
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
using (XmlTextReader xReader = new XmlTextReader(reader))
{
    XmlDocument pathDoc = new XmlDocument();
    pathDoc.Load(xReader);
}
```

Comment: [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization) ;o)

Comment: The most efficient way is doing what you're already doing. Any other way is just add unnecessary complexity to the code and possible break things in the future.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, you may be able to get away with using an XML reader only (i.e., not building a full fledged XmlDocument).  But, that tends to result in a lot of code, sometimes a lot of fragile code

Comment: I need to have dozens of threads running concurrently and performing this operation quickly on xml strings. I just need to convert the string to an XmlDocument